# Ajax, show page only if reached by clicking the link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, load

I have implemented a small system that loads the content of links in a div on the main page and update the url of the page in order to speed navigation.

I am, however, faced with a problem. The main styles (usufruisco of bootstrap css) are contained in the index (index.php). If you load the contents of a page (ajax) for the index in the div, styles are correct. But if I go to another page directly (not through the link but typing the url in the address bar of your browser), styles do not exist and so the page does not appear well.

Is there an acceptable solution to remedy this?

Comment: I had to heavily edit your text. Please *do not* post questions that are auto-translated from another language. The result is really hard to understand. I don't think I was able to fix all the problems in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have understood is that you want to show something only when the request is through an ajax call.

If that is so, then use the following code:

```
if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
    // Do the ajax processing 
} else {
    // Redirect to desired page
}
```

Comment: Great, just what I was looking for, I would, could you explain the function of **$ _SERVER ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']**. Thank you.

Comment: Anytime:) 

HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is the header sent by the browsers.